# Why android doesn't recognize second activity when i launch it with an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am having a weird error popping up when click listener attempts to open a new activity:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.example.room2n.practice8/com.example.room2n.practice8.NewDbaActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

It's weird because I can't point out any problem in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NewDbaActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also, it's the triggering function:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewDbaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: That is weird. I have tried replicating your problem and would like to inform you that it functioning flawlessly. Have you saved your Manifest file? Also, you can try clean and rebuild the project before running it again. Secondly, try changing the app theme from AppTheme.NoActionBar to plain AppTheme and run it again.

Comment: On similar project (basically the same one, just different variable name and etc.) it's working perfectly too, I tried comparing them and couldn't find anything that might cause it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your newly created Activity in AndroidManifest.xml file. Like for example as follows above :

```
<activity
            android:name=".NewDbaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_yourTitle"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Something that i see you have already done. I would suggest looking on the path of the *second activity*, is that inside a **package**? since i can read something like : practice8 .. if so you need to state it like .practice8.NewDbaActivity .

PS : I saw your **edit** of the question and this causes the problem. You have changed and messed them up by editing the lines. So follow the previous way based on the package name.